AWS Amplify Function - Scan all items in a DynamoDB Table
I'm trying to scan all items in a DynamoDB Table. This table has 23,000 items and it's size is 660.2MB.
I'm using AWS Amplify on my React project and using AWS Lambda(function in Amplify) with REST API.
I've been getting 502 Bad Gateway error while scanning all data. The function keeps shutting down while scanning the table. I thought it could be memory issue, so I increased the memory size of the function to 2GB, but still the same.
What should I do to scan all data without error?
Here is the code of my lambda function:
async function getPrice(params) {
  try {
    let allItems = [];
    console.log('Querying Table');

    const data = await ddbDocClient.send(new ScanCommand(params));
    if (data['Items'].length > 0) {
      allItems = [...allItems, ...data.Items];
    }

    console.log('has next data? ', data.LastEvaluatedKey);

    if (data.LastEvaluatedKey) {
      params.ExclusiveStartKey = data.LastEvaluatedKey;
      return await getPrice(params);
    } else {
      console.log('end with items: ', allItems.length);
      return allItems;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('DynamoDB error: ', err);
    return err;
  }
}

app.get(path, async function (req, res) {
  var params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    Select: 'ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
  };

  try {
    const data = await getPrice(params);
    res.json(data);
  } catch (err) {
    res.statusCode = 500;
    res.json({ error: 'Could not load items: ' + err.message });
  }
});


Note that both AWS Lambda and API Gateway have payload limits (6 MB and 10 MB respectively). Also, Lambda functions have a configurable timeout.

In addition to what jarmod said, did you check what the error is in Cloudwatch logs for your Lambda function? It may be timeout (especially if you used default Lambda settings). Another thing to consider - do you need all the data about all the objects? If not, you can create an index and scan less data. Are you using provisioned mode, or on-demand? In provisioned mode you can get ProvisionedThroughputExceededException when you don't have enough capacity provisioned

Firstly, increase the memory and timeout of the function. I'll be attaching my pagination code using next token. Next token has to be added in the mapping template. You can limit the items to be sent.
(Note: Its an async function and scan_dynamo function is defined elsewhere and being called here. I couldn't format the code with whole function here, so just the try block.)
try {
let listCategoryParams= {
  TableName: "your_table_name",
  Limit: 50 //set as required(not more than 250 preferably)
};
if (event.next_token) {
  listUserParams.ExclusiveStartKey = JSON.parse(Buffer.from(event.next_token.trim(), "base64").toString("ascii"));
}
let category = await scan_dynamo(listCategoryParams);
if (category.Count > 0) {
  let response = {};
  response.items = category.Items.sort((a, b) => b.category_created_on - a.category_created_on);//only if you wanna sort it by creation time
  if (category.LastEvaluatedKey) {
    response.next_token = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(category.LastEvaluatedKey)).toString("base64");
  }
  return { status: "Success", data: response };
}

